# I2c to CAN conversion in STM32f4 via waijung Blockset Matlab Simulink

Tags: microcontroller, simulink, i2c, stm32f4discovery, can-bus

I want to convert (OMRON ELECTRONIC COMPONENTS D6T-8L-06) Heat Sensor's output which is in I2C format via STM32f4 to CAN. And i want to do this conversion in Matlab Simulink using Waijung Blockset. i am able to read the sensor but there is no conversion technique available for STM32f4. This CAN message will be further utilized in XPC target PC

Comment: You can read the sensor but you can't convert it? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I can read the signal via receiving I2C block available in Waijung Blockset but i am unable to convert the signal to CAN. I need to know the protocols or technique to convert I2C to CAN